# how to genrate uniq id if we send the data using seprate comma

Tags: php

i m try to use uniqid() to genrate the uniqname of the file and send it to the sql db by spliting  seprate comma like('pic.jpg','pic1.jpg','pic2.jpg')
in place of pic i need a uniq name each and every time at the time of uploading of the file,i store all uploaded file into a folder and send the path of the image to the sql

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
    $rep=$_FILES['files']['name']; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($rep); $i++) {    
        if ($_FILES["files"]["size"][$i] < 1000000) { // Check File size (Allow 1MB)             
            $nam=$_FILES["files"]["name"][$i];
            // $nm = $_FILES["files"]["name"];
        $album_cat = "";
            $l = 0;
           foreach ($rep as $album_cat1) {
               $album_cat .= $album_cat1 . ",";
               $l++;
           }
           $_POST['$album_cat'] = $album_cat;
           $_POST['$album_cat_count'] = $l;        
            $temp = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i];
            $name = pathinfo($nam);
            $profile = "group_images/" . uniqid() . '.' . $name['extension'];            
            if (empty($temp)) {
                break;
            }
            if ($i == 0) {
                $err = "File uploaded successfully";
              $cls = "success";
            }
             $groupalbum = "UPDATE group_master SET group_photo='".$_POST['$album_cat']."' WHERE group_id='4'";

            //$groupalbum = "UPDATE group_master SET group_photo='$profile' WHERE group_id='4'";
            if ($conn->query($groupalbum) === TRUE) {              
            } else
                echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
                move_uploaded_file($temp, $profile);         
        }
        else {
            $err = "File size is more than 1MB";
            $cls = "danger";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please add your form, or at least the file input parts.

Comment: Has the answer i've given helped you?? Or do you still feel lost?

Comment: may be in some other case it will be help full but on here onwords nope????..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need an uniqid for a set of elements, I usually call uniqid() only once and after that I use an index (just for optimizing the speed of the script). So, you can call `uniqid()` before the `for` declaration:

```
$rep=$_FILES['files']['name'];
$uniqid = uniqid();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($rep); $i++) {
```

and then use `$i` as a suffix for your files

```
 $profile = "group_images/".$uniqid.'-'.$i.'.'.$name['extension'];
```

On the other hand, you are calling `move_uploaded_file($temp, $profile);` only if your sql fails.

```
if ($conn->query($groupalbum) === TRUE) {              
} else
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    move_uploaded_file($temp, $profile);         
}
```

Are you sure that the logic is correct? Don't you need something like:

```
if ($conn->query($groupalbum) === TRUE) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($temp, $profile)) {
        // file has been uploaded successfully
    } else {
        // error in file upload process
    }        
} else
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;        
}
```

And the final point, your code is open for sql injection

```
$groupalbum = "UPDATE group_master SET group_photo='".$_POST['$album_cat']."' WHERE group_id='4'";
```

You should not use $_POST values directly into sql statements.